# MySQL Stored Procedure with like Operator

Tags: mysql

i trie to run this statement:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`daimler_bkUser`@`%` PROCEDURE `expatSuchen`(IN SUCHBEGRIFF VARCHAR(60))
BEGIN
 Select * from expats where Last_Name LIKE CONCAT('%', SUCHBEGRIFF , '%');
END
```

But MySQL gives me the following error:

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '()' at line 1

Comment: Are you sure the error is coming from that query? There's no `()` anywhere in it.

Comment: Have you tried copying the query into mysqlWorkbench and run it there?

Comment: No error in Workbench

Comment: I think you are sending empty value in `SUCHBEGRIFF` parameter